# Access localhost PostgreSQL & Redis from a dockerized app

Tags: docker, docker-network

I recently started move my app into docker. A dockerfile is fine, docker image build is ok. But when I start the container I see errors related to the PostgreSQL & Redis. 
I understood that the application is isolated in the container and can not access PostgreSQL (`127.0.0.1:5432`) & Redis (`127.0.0.1:6379`) which run locally on my laptop.

The question is: **how to access the DBs which run locally on my laptop from the docker container app?**

I think that this will be helpful when I'll deploy the app in prod. Because prod DBs run on different hosts. 
But at first it's important to access DB from local laptop.

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel no I did not. I didn't find any `--net` argument for `run` docker command. Probably you talk about `--network`? O_o

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel no. This is not a duplicate. I have already read the question you mentioned, it doesn't feet to my question

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel just tried it:
/n docker run -i --network=127.0.0.1 fruzenshtein/akka-delete-me:latest
/n docker: Error response from daemon: network 127.0.0.1 not found.
/n ERRO[0000] error getting events from daemon: context canceled

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel still does not work: SEVERE: Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel I googled a lot, but haven't found any answer which may help to solve this :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148338/discussion-between-alex-fruzenshtein-and-francois-maturel).